# Extrair dados de todas as linhas de um arquivo e criar um dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

Tenho um arquivo .txt com 2000 linhas (chat do whatsapp) de onde preciso extrair para um pandas dataframe a data, hora e emissor da mensagem.  Eu consigo fazer isso com a função abaixo:

```
def parse(file):
  
    data = re.search(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}',file )
    hora = re.search(r'\d{2}:\d{2}', file)
    pessoa = re.search(r'(?<=\-)(.*?)(?=\:)',file)
    return data.group(0), hora.group(0), pessoa.group(0)
```

que funciona perfeitamente para uma linha do tipo:

```
    file = ('20/05/2020 20:35 - Rodrigo Toledo:')
    parse(file)
```

Porém quero uma forma de aplicar a função parse em todas as linhas do arquivo .txt, para depois transformar em um dataframe.

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo de erro? Outro tipo de dado com o qual seu código deve funcionar

Comment: O  codigo deve sempre funcionar com um arquivo txt cujas linhas seguem o padrao ('20/05/2020 20:35 - Rodrigo Toledo:').  o txt tem 2000 linhas, entao preciso que a função parse percorra estas 2000 linhas, savando cada linha executada em um outro arquivo que servirá de base para criação de um dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o formato é sempre esse, você pode usar uma regex para extrair todos os dados de uma vez, ir guardando os resultados em uma lista e no final criar o dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

r = re.compile(r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}) (\d{2}:\d{2}) - ([^:]+)')
itens = []
with open('dados.txt') as arq:
    for linha in arq: # para cada linha do arquivo
        m = r.match(linha)
        if m: # se a regex encontrou um match, adiciona na lista
            itens.append(m.groups())

# cria o dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(itens, columns=['data', 'hora', 'nome'])
```

Na regex eu coloco os trechos correspondentes à data, hora e o nome. Para a data e hora, usei o mesmo que você já estava usando: a quantidade de números e os separadores.

Para o nome, usei `[^:]+`, que é "um ou mais caracteres que **não** sejam `:`". Assim eu pego tudo depois do hífen até o `:`.

E cada um desses trechos está entre parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](http://regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), assim eu consigo pegar tudo de uma vez com o [método `groups`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups), que retorna uma tupla com todos os grupos.

Ao final do *loop*, a lista `itens` terá várias tuplas, cada uma contendo a data, hora e nome.

Depois é só criar o dataframe e escolher os nomes das colunas (como exemplo, usei os criativos nomes "data", "hora" e "nome").

Comment: Funcionou perfeiramente. Muito Obrigado. Ultimo probleminha: em cada linha eu tenho um segundo : como pego tudo depois deste segundo sinal de : ?

Comment: @Pouchewar Se for para pegar tudo até o próximo `:` é só colocar mais um grupo de captura: `re.compile(r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}) (\d{2}:\d{2}) - ([^:]+):([^:]+)')` - lembrando que ao criar o dataframe tem que colocar o nome da quarta coluna também. Mas se quer pegar tudo até o final da linha, use `re.compile(r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}) (\d{2}:\d{2}) - ([^:]+):(.+)')` - lembrando que nesse caso `.+` vai pegar tudo até o final da linha, então depende do que você precisa

Comment: Muito Obrigado. Ajudou muito.